# Canvas vs. img - performance

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to find some relevant sources about this and found nothing.

So, my questions are quite simple.
Is canvas faster than img? I will use object as in img (png, gif) or canvas.

1. Object is used only once,
2. multiple use of same object, for example icons at admin,
3. multiple use of different objects, for example logos of companies.

I am interested in memory usage, performance in browser and in loading speed.

edit#1: canvas is drawn by js and it will be same as image in img tag.

Comment: You mean *drawing something on a `<canvas>`* vs. *an `<img>` tag*? "Faster" in what way? Download speed? Rendering speed?

Comment: yes i mean...i will edit question, thank you

Comment: In almost all cases this is a total non-issue. You should use canvas when you need canvas and img when you need img. Choose based on your need and optimize *only* when it becomes necessary.

Comment: This question is asking about performance on two very common HTML elements, I don't understand why it was closed as too localized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `img` is faster, easier to create and more accessible than using `canvas`. **The `img` tag was designed to show an image** so if that's all you need to do, use an `img` tag. Multiple uses shouldn't matter as the image will only be downloaded once.

If you need some animation or interactivity, that is the time to consider `canvas`.

Comment: Is `img` faster? Could you explain why please?

Comment: @Robula `img` is built to just draw images, everything is handled in native code. For a `canvas`, you need to create the DOM element, grab the image somehow (potentially via an `img` element), then draw it. They are built to be general canvases for drawing all sorts of things, `img`'s are simple and therefore better for just drawing images.

Comment: Thank you for the the clarification. I was under the impression Canvas may be more performant as it utilised WebGL.