# How to add tiles nested in leaflet map to canvas with latest version of react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I'm trying to add map on the canvas and put tiles there with react-leaflet library v3.X. At the moment tiles are displaying as `<img>` in HTML. In latest versions of react-leaflet there isn't Map object there is MapContainer object only. So I can't add property preferCanvas=true to MapContainer. It is noteworthy that in old versions of react-leaflet there was Map object with preferCanvas option but then it was removed. I think another way to add map to canvas exists. Please, help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { MapContainer as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

// some code skipped
return (
<LeafletMap
  preferCanvas={true} // не работает
  center={[51.65, 103.72]}
  zoom={14}
  maxZoom={16}
  attributionControl={true}
  zoomControl={true}
  doubleClickZoom={false}
  scrollWheelZoom={true}
  dragging={true}
  animate={true}
  easeLinearity={0.35}
  whenReady={(map) => {
    setMapReady(true);
  }}
>
  <TileLayer
    url="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}"
    id="mapbox/outdoors-v11"
  />
</LeafletMap>
  );
}
```

Comment: It exists. If you type ctlr + space and then p the option will popup. It is available.

Comment: @kboul I have tried it in VSCode. Unfortunately there isn't. react-leaflet v3.1.0. leaflet 1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preferCanvas` was never intended to render tilelayer tiles as canvas elements.  [From the docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-prefercanvas):

> Whether Paths should be rendered on a Canvas renderer. By default, all Paths are rendered in a SVG renderer.

What you want to do is not built into leaflet, but is not too uncommon.  Rather than build it *totally* from scratch, it looks like someone already built [L.TileLayer.Canvas](https://github.com/GIAPspzoo/L.TileLayer.Canvas) for vanilla leaflet.  So all we need to do is bring it into react-leaflet.  You can follow [these docs on the react-leaflet website](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-architecture#element-hook-factory) to create a custom react-leaflet component that is built from L.TileLayer.Canvas:

```js
import { createLayerComponent } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import L from "leaflet";
import "tilelayer-canvas";

const createLayer = (props, context) => {
  const instance = L.tileLayer.canvas(props.url, { ...props });

  return { instance, context };
};

const updateLayer = (instance, props, prevProps) => {
  // you may not need all of these
  //or you may need others I didn't include here:
  if (prevProps.url !== props.url) {
    if (instance.setUrl) instance.setUrl(props.url);
  }
  if (prevProps.opacity !== props.opacity) {
    if (instance.setOpacity) instance.setOpacity(props.opacity);
  }
  if (prevProps.zIndex !== props.zIndex) {
    if (instance.setZIndex) instance.setZIndex(props.zIndex);
  }
};

const TilelayerCanvas = createLayerComponent(createLayer, updateLayer);

export default TilelayerCanvas;
```

Now in your map:

```js
import TilelayerCanvas from "./TilelayerCanvas";

const Map = (props) => {
  return (
    <MapContainer ... >
      <TilelayerCanvas url="the_url" attribution="some_attribution" />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tilelayer-canvas-lj2zn)

If you check the devtools, you'll see that tiles are rendered as canvas elements instead of img elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think my queston isn't correct. I expected to put tiles on the canvas but they are displayed as <img>.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i wanted. How do you think is it better for performance than displaying as <img>? I see there are many `<canvas>` blocks. They are created for each image. I hope finally all of them will work as one <canvas>

Comment: I'm no expert but my experience is that img is more performant, especially when decising how to render tiles in leaflet. That idea is supported in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541183/canvas-vs-img-performance).  If you want all the tiles to be stitched together into a single canvas, that's a whole other task, and I don't think that would be performant at all.